# fb:login-button not showing up in Firefox, IE, or Opera - but works fine in Chrome

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

This seemed to happen without any changes on my part. Suddenly any browser but Chrome was not processing the fb:login-button tag, it's just showing any text within the tag as plain text.

After scouring the net for hours, looking for possible causes/solutions, I've found nothing that addresses this particular behavior.

So, I've created the most basic example I could to illustrate the problem, and put it up here:
http://silverbucket.net/examples/fblogin/welcome.htm

The above example shows a fb-login box in Chrome, but not in Firefox, IE, or Opera.

In summary, what is in the page in the above link, first there's the html tag at the top I have:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" lang="en">
```

In the head I have:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

In the body, just below the header I have:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Then there's the actual fb-login-button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="email, user_interests, user_likes, publish_stream">log in with facebook</fb:login-button>
```

And, at the bottom of the page, just before the closing of the body tag, I have the FB JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId   : '153787078069017',
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
        //channelUrl : '/channel.html', // channel.html file
        oauth   : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
        status : false
      });

      // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          window.location.href="http://example.com/fblogin";
        }
      });
    };

    (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
      e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

  });
</script>
```

Nothing complicated... and it's not just happening on my Firefox, but every colleague I've checked with as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest moving `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {`  to outside of the `$(document).ready(function() {`.  This should give more consistent results browser to browser.

Comment: thanks very much for your suggestion, this did the trick. I wonder why it worked for so long, and then decided to break.

Comment: It's all in how the browser loads the various resources whether or not they are being loaded serially, or in parallel.  And also in what order they do get loaded in.  Also of note would be what files the browser doesn't need to download but rather grab from local cache.  It's best to define the window.fbAsyncInit as early as possible so it can be run when the SDK is finally loaded.  :)  Happy coding!

Comment: Ah, I see. It's weird because there are a lot of examples and writings from people who say that it shouldn't be initialized until after the entire document is completely finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but try adding your fb-root div before the actual code including the login button if this is possible.

That has solved some of the fb quirks I've faced before.

Comment: i updated the example link with the fb-root div just below the page header. doesn't seem to have any effect.